# Must provide source or customer. rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, stripe-payments

when I attempt to run my code, I got the error above. i don't understand why I get this, everything seems clear to me..

Here's my controller's create action :

```
def create
    @user = current_user
    @order = current_order
    @amount = @order.subtotal
    token = params[:stripeToken]

  charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
    :amount      => (@amount.to_i * 100),
    :description => 'Rails Stripe customer',
    :currency    => 'eur',
    :source      => token
  )

  redirect_to root_path

rescue Stripe::CardError => e
  flash[:error] = e.message
  render 'new'
end
```

my form :

```
<%= form_tag pay_path, html: { id: 'payment-form' }  do %>
<div class="row">
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div style="position: absolute; left: 20px">
    <label class="control-label" for="email">Email</label>
    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="you@example.com" style="width: 25em"/>
  </div>
  <div style="position: absolute; left: 400px">
    <label class="control-label" for="number">Card Number</label>
    <input type="text" size="20" data-stripe="number" id="number" placeholder="**** **** **** ****" pattern="[\d ]*" style="width: 18em"/>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row" style="margin-top: 65px">
  <div style="position: absolute; left: 20px">
    <label class="control-label" for="cvc">CVC</label>
    <input type="text" style="width: 3em" size="3" data-stripe="cvc" id="cvc" placeholder="***" pattern="\d*"/>
    <img id="card-image" src="/img/credit.png" style="height: 30px; padding-left: 10px; margin-top: -10px">
  </div>
  <div style="position: absolute; left: 150px">
    <label class="control-label">Exp (MM/YYYY)</label>
    <input style="width: 2em" type="text" size="2" id="exp-month" data-stripe="exp-month" placeholder="MM" pattern="\d*"/>
    <span> / </span>
    <input style="width: 3em" type="text" size="4" id="exp-year" data-stripe="exp-year" placeholder="YYYY" pattern="\d*"/>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row" style="margin-top: 70px">
  <div class="price" style="position: absolute; left: 20px;"><%= @amount %></div>
  <div style="position: absolute; left: 400px">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-large">Buy Now</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

my layouts/application.html.erb :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.stripe.com/v2/">    </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
  Stripe.setPublishableKey('<%=    Rails.configuration.stripe[:publishable_key] %>');
});
</script>
```

I saw so many resources on this topic, but none helped me.
Any idea ?

EDIT :

routes.rb :

```
post '/payer-la-commande', to: 'transactions#create',   as: :pay
```

EDIT 2

error :

```
[localhost] [127.0.0.1] [1f4eb06b-26d4-41] Processing by    TransactionsController#create as HTML
[localhost] [127.0.0.1] [1f4eb06b-26d4-41]   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"67gwUvgY1xxxxxxxxxxxmtqwHyHQs3TUoanH6EDUx7wkCMVQIdqcxEuQEjoSUc/AXThw==", "email"=>""}
[localhost] [127.0.0.1] [1f4eb06b-26d4-41]   User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 2  ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
[localhost] [127.0.0.1] [1f4eb06b-26d4-41]   Order Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  `orders`.* FROM `orders` WHERE `orders`.`id` = 2 LIMIT 1
[localhost] [127.0.0.1] [1f4eb06b-26d4-41]   OrderItem Load (1.1ms)  SELECT `order_items`.* FROM `order_items` WHERE `order_items`.`order_id` = 2
[localhost] [127.0.0.1] [1f4eb06b-26d4-41]   Product Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  `products`.* FROM `products` WHERE `products`.`active` = 1 AND `products`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
[localhost] [127.0.0.1] [1f4eb06b-26d4-41] Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 4197ms (ActiveRecord: 2.1ms)
[localhost] [127.0.0.1] [1f4eb06b-26d4-41] 
Stripe::InvalidRequestError (Must provide source or customer.):
  app/controllers/transactions_controller.rb:16:in `create'
```

from stripe logs, Parsed Request POST Body :

```
amount: "100"
description: "Rails Stripe customer"
currency: "eur"
```

EDIT 3 :

```
POST http://localhost:3000/payer-la-commande 500 (Internal Server Error)
Navigated to http://localhost:3000/payer-la-commande
content.js:4 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'unique' of nullinit @ content.js:4(anonymous function) @ content.js:10
2content.js:4 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'unique' of nullinit @ content.js:4(anonymous function) @ VM658:1
```

[image]

Comment: What's the value of `params[:stripeToken]` when that action is called? That's the value being sent to source and it should be a Stripe.js token.

Comment: I have no value for now

Answer (score 2):

`params[:stripeToken]` is blank because you are missing the javascript that sends the form to stripe, gets a token value, puts it on a hidden field and sends that to the server (rails) see https://stripe.com/docs/tutorials/forms#create-a-single-use-token for additional information.

EDIT: Once you have the token, you have to send it to the server using something like https://stripe.com/docs/tutorials/forms#sending-the-form-to-your-server (same document than before, just read it entirely)

Comment: Update your question with all the information you have? Is `stripeResponseHandler` being called? What's the value of `response.id (token)` then? You need to help us more by sharing more information.

Comment: Thanks for your responses, actually, the only error I got is the one I added to the second EDIT. How to bring up the js errors, with pry ?

Comment: On your browsers console (visible by opening Developer Tools or right clicking any element and "Inspect" or similar). Similar to `byebug` or `debugger` in rails, you can use "debugger" in JS, but it will only stop when the developer tools are open, or simply use `console.log(variable)` to output  stuff to the console. You should do a quick read on debugging javascript on the browser. Keep editing your question with all the information you find.

Comment: I just deleted everything and rewrite and it works , thank you for your help.